# Ruby, Create a Custom Error Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, custom-error-handling

Here's the code, but a lot of it is irrelevant:

```
class BankAccount

def initialize(first_name, last_name)
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
    @balance = 0
end

def public_deposit(amount)
    @balance += amount
end

def protected_deposit(amount)
    @balance += amount
end
protected :protected_deposit

def private_deposit(amount)
    @balance += amount
end
private :private_deposit

def call_private_deposit(amount)
    private_deposit(amount)
end

def call_protected_deposit(amount)
    protected_deposit(amount)
end

#To show that you can't call a private method with a different instance of the same class.
def private_add_to_different_account(account, amount)
    account.private_deposit(amount)
end

#To show that you can call a protected method with a different instance of the same class.
def protected_add_to_different_account(account, amount)
    account.protected_deposit(amount)
end
end
```

I load this code into irb using "load './visibility.rb'" and then create an instance:

```
an_instance = BankAccount.new("Joe", "Bloggs")
```

Then, I generate a NoMethodError by typing:

```
an_instance.protected_deposit(1000)
```

This returns a NoMethodError. This is intentional. However, what I want to happen is for a custom message to be returned instead of the standard NoMethodError - something like "This is a custom error message."

I've been hacking away at this for hours and I'm at my wits end. I'm a relative beginner, so please bear this in mind.

Thanks.

Comment: What you want to do is to override `method_missing`

Answer (score 0):

You can rescue the error:

```
def call_protected_method
  instance = BankAccount.new("Joe", "Bloggs")
  instance.protected_deposit(1000)
rescue NoMethodError
  puts "You called a protected method"
end
```

If you want to return a custom message, you can rescue the error and raise your own custom exception. Ruby lets you define your own exception classes. But I can't imagine why you would want to do this. You already have a built in exception to handle this.

Comment: This is ok, but I want it to happen inside irb

Comment: @Andy I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by that!